# What is a best practice naming convention for DOJO widgets that can be initiated only once?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have defined a custom widget for my DOJO app using `PascalCase` notation     (`CustomPanel.js`)

In my app I usually use PascalCase notation for widgets that can be initiate in several points in the app and where more object of type `CustomPanel` can be present at the same time.

In my specific example below, I need to create a class for a custom widget `PanelCustomer.js`. This specific widget can be exclusively **initiate only once** in the entire application.

I would like your opinion on:

- As this widget can be initiated only once in the app should the file be names `panelCustomer.js` (camelCase) and initiate like `new panelCusotmer();`?
- Does it make sense to have a widget designed as a singletone object instead? Could you provide me an example?
- Do you know a better approach?

---

```
  define([
        'app/_Panel',
        'dojo/_base/declare',
        'dijit/_WidgetBase',
        'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
        'dojo/text!./templates/PanelCustomer.html',
        'dojo/topic'
    ], function (
        _Panel,
        declare,
        _WidgetBase,
        _TemplatedMixin,
        template,
        topic
        ) {
        return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _Panel], {
            templateString: template,
            appType: 'PanelCustomer',
            id: 'panelCustomer',
            title: 'Customer',
            postCreate: function () {
                this.inherited(arguments);
                this._render();
            },
            _render: function () {
                this._addBtn = new Button({
                    id: 'addBtn',
                    label: 'Add',
                    onClick: function () {

                    }.bind(this)
                }, 'addBtn');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use PascalCase for the widget names as they'll be used as constructors and camelCase for your functions. Most javascript libraries also follow this convention and that's why I would recommend it.

I can't think of a reason right now as to why a Widget should be a singleton but ultimately it really depends on what you're trying to do with your app.

In your situation, are you trying to instantiate PanelCustomer once for the entire application or just once per customer? From the way you've named it, it sounds like it should be once per customer.

If you did want to make a singleton, all you would have to do is initialize your widget before returning it.

```
    var PanelCustomer =  declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _Panel], {
        templateString: template,
        appType: 'PanelCustomer',
        id: 'panelCustomer',
        title: 'Customer',
        postCreate: function () {
            this.inherited(arguments);
            this._render();
        },
        _render: function () {
            this._addBtn = new Button({
                id: 'addBtn',
                label: 'Add',
                onClick: function () {

                }.bind(this)
            }, 'addBtn');
        }
    });

    return new PanelCustomer();
```

Comment: In my case I would have only ONE PanelCustomer for the entire application.. Please let me know your toughs. Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: A singleton pattern should be fine here although I'd need to know more before I can really say for sure why you would need a singleton pattern with a widget as opposed to the widget being passed around. But I've edited my answer to show you how to make a singleton with Dojo